# Bizarre set of symptoms after installing new netgear router

Tags: router

I just upgraded an old BT router for a new netgear DG834. The installation all appeared to go fine. I can now view every website I can think of and all works well except www.bbc.co.uk. If I try typing that into my browser a dialog box appears requesting a username and password!

The message is:

```
The server www.bbc.co.uk at NETGEAR DG834   requires a username and password.

Warning: This server is requesting that your username and password 
be sent in an insecure manner (basic authentication without a secure connection).
```

Any ideas what may be going on?

**UPDATE:** A reboot made the problem go away. I am still curious to know what happened, but it is no longer a real problem.

Comment: Some kind of internet content filtering perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your router is probably also you DNS cache/forwarder. Somehow a DNS request for `www.bbc.co.uk` has returned your routers internal IP address (Why I can't tell). Your browser connected happily to the admin interface, to greet you with the password dialog.

Comment: I may never know the true answer for certain - but your answer sounds very plausible, so I'll mark it as correct :-)